# What is the "customize" feature associated with defcustom and used in projectile.el?

Tags: customize, projectile, defcustom

Asking this question because it's really hard to Google "emacs customize" and get to the feature.

From the [`defcustom` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/defcustom.html):

> You can specify variables using `defcustom` so that you and others can then use Emacs’s `customize` feature to set their values. (You cannot use customize to write function definitions; but you can write `defuns` in your .emacs file. Indeed, you can write any Lisp expression in your .emacs file.)
>
> The `customize` feature depends on the `defcustom` macro. Although you can use `defvar` or `setq` for variables that users set, the defcustom macro is designed for the job.

I haven't been able to figure out what "customize" is from this definition.

For completeness I am reading the [`projectile.el`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el#L131) source code where this is used (although I don't really expect the answer to depend on the package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"customize feature" there should probably be written as "Customize feature" or "the Customize user interface" or some such.

Try `M-x customize-option` or `M-x customize-face` or `M-x customize`.

See the Emacs manual, node [`Easy Customization`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html).

And remember that the Emacs manual is your friend:
`C-h r i customize RET` takes you to the above part of the manual.

If Projectile is normal then you should be able to use `M-x customize-group projectile` or `M-x customize-option projectile TAB` or some such (depending on what Customize group(s) and prefix Projectile has defined).